# Print values of an array between two concenctric circles

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have two concenctric circles. I know want to write a python script, which prints me only the values of the array between the radius 2 and 5. How can I do this?
This is what I have done so far:
[image: concenctric circles]

```
import numpy as np
positions = np.array([[2.5, 8], [3, 10], [0, 5], [1, 5], [7, 8]])
x = positions[:, 0]
y = positions[:, 1]

def isInsideO(circle_x, circle_y, rad1, x, y):
   return (x,y,((x - circle_x) ** 2 + (y - circle_y) ** 2) <= rad1 ** 2)

def isInsideI(circle_x, circle_y, rad2, x, y):
   return (x,y,((x - circle_x) ** 2 + (y - circle_y) ** 2) >= rad2 ** 2)

circle_x = 0;
circle_y = 5;
rad1 = 5;
rad2 = 2;

is_insideO = isInsideO(circle_x, circle_y, rad1, x, y)
is_insideI = isInsideI(circle_x, circle_y, rad2, x, y)
output = ""
for i in range(len(is_insideO[2])):
       for k in range(len(is_insideI[2])):

  output += "[{x}, {y}]".format(x=is_inside[0][i][k], y=is_inside[1][i][k]) if is_insideI[2][k]<=is_insideO[i] else "".format(x=is_inside[0][i][k], y=is_inside[1][i][k])
print(output.strip(","))
```

Comment: You can just check all x and y from x = bigger radius to x= -bigger radius. Do the same to y.

Comment: What it your current problem? what is the expected output? Also you probably do not need 2 functions, it is doing the same thing, just with inverse output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you want is to calculate the area of the area between the two circles, calculate the area for each circle, then return the difference between the biggest circle, and the smallest one.

```
from math import pi

def areaBetween(x, y):
    # Area of bigger/outer circle
    biggercircle = pi * x * x
 
    # Area of smaller/inner circle
    smallercircle = pi * y * y
 
    # Difference in areas
    return biggercircle - smallercircle 
 
# Define the radius of each circle
x = 5 # Biggest circle
y = 2 # Smallest circle
 
print(areaBetween(x, y))
>>> 65.97344572538566
```